# How to represent sqrt(-1) in programming?

Tags: c++, math

I want to represent `sqrt(-1)` in C++, because I am trying to implement an FFT algorithm. Is there a good way of representing this?

Comment: Out of interest is there a good reason why you'd want to write an FFT routine yourself rather than using something like [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)?

Comment: just i am reading algorithm books  introduction to algorithms (MIT press), so  just training no more

Comment: You could always ask [Marvin](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf458) (see last large yellow boxed text at bottom of page)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `#include <complex>` e.g.:

```
std::complex<double> num(0,1);
```

You can actually use `std::sqrt` with this `complex` type to compute `sqrt(-1)`:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const std::complex<double> result = std::sqrt(std::complex<double>(-1,0));
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

For `wn=exp((2*pi*i)/n)` you can do:

```
const double pi = std::acos(-1.0);
const std::complex<double> i(0,1);

std::complex<double> wn = std::exp((2*pi*i)/double(n));
```

Comment: And `complex<double> i(0, 1);` is the desired value.

Comment: one question  we know  that,in FFT  method  wn=exp((2*pi*i)/n)  so how would it be?

Comment: @user466534 - added an example for that

Comment: @ awoodland  / can't be  with complex numbers,why?

Comment: @user466534 - `operator/` and `operator/=` are implemented for `std::complex`. You do however need to be careful to make the template selection work, for example `std::complex<double>(1,1) / 1` won't work but `std::complex<double>(1,1) / 1.0` will work. I'd guess you're trying to do complex/real division with an `int` type.

Comment: in my case n=8 ,i have wrote it   as double wn = std::exp((2*pi*i)/8.0); but error  is this  1>c:\users\datuashvili\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex\complex\complex.cpp(13): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::complex<double>' to 'double'

Comment: I don't think that's the division causing the problem there - break it down into smaller expressions with extra variables to see what it is. My guess is that it's a problem with trying to pick the `double` version of `std::exp` for some reason because it can't see the complex version.

Comment: @user466534: `wn` should be `std::complex<double>`, not `double`.

Comment: @user466534 - it should work and does work on my machine, (GCC/Linux) but it's really hard for me to remotely debug

Comment: @MikeSeymour - good spot! I was just printing the return value without storing it in a variable on my test case.

Comment: ok,then i am going now  to install linux(installation is in process)it is ubuntu,so i hope that it will work

Comment: @user466534 - Mike Seymour spotted a mistake in my example that will fix the error you were seeing.

Comment: @PaulR: Not before I commented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a `Complex` class you should include: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/