# C++ complex number multiplication

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

If I have (1+i)^2, the answer should be 2i

But if I do

```
std::complex<double> i = sqrt(1), one = 1;
cout << pow(one+i,2) << endl;
```

It outputs `(4,0)`

Comment: The square root of 1 is not i.

Comment: No, it is not even the square root of -1. So better use `std::complex<double> i(0,1);`

Comment: Your output all follows from `1+1=2`

Comment: @andi by convention, *the* square root of `-x` (for `x>0`) refers to `i` times the positive square root of `x`

Comment: @andi: How did you get to `sqrt(-1*-1)` from `sqrt(-1)*sqrt(-1)`?

Comment: I'm feeling pretty dumb right about now, what a ridiculous mistake on my part!

Comment: @andi: No, it doesn't explain it. It just begs the opposite question. How did you get to `sqrt(-1)*sqrt(-1)` from `sqrt(-1 * -1)`?

Comment: @andi: Because, just because a rule applies for one set of numbers, does not mean it must apply for a different set of numbers.

Comment: @ Benjamin Lindley: You are right, the "proof" is ****! Sorry about that. However, i is still defined as i*i = -1 and not sqrt(-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are initializing `i` to `sqrt(1)` whereas you probably thought about `sqrt(-1)`.
As such it would be evaluated as a `double` expression (after -1 is converted to double as the closest matching `sqrt`, see Mike's comment for complete sequence), which according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/) generates a domain error for negative arguments.

Instead you can initialize `i` as:

```
std::complex<double> i(0,1);
```

Alternatively you could use a complex number as argument to `sqrt` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819404/how-to-represent-sqrt-1-in-programming#answer-7819420), or as Potatoswatter indicated in comments you could use `1.i` with C++14 (should you have a compiler & standard library that supports [user-defined literals for standard library types, part 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3779.pdf)).

Comment: I'd be happier with this answer if it explained why `sqrt(-1)` is the wrong syntax, since that seems to be a key part of the OP's confusion.

Comment: `std::complex<double> i = sqrt(-1)` effectively does the following in this order: 1) create an integer value "-1" 2) try to pass it to `sqrt()`, which has `double` and `complex<double>` versions. `double` is the closer typecast, so it implicitly casts `-1` to `-1.0` and calls `double sqrt(double)`. 3) That function can't deal with negative numbers, so it sets `errno` to `EDOM` and returns an undefined `double`. 4) That `double` gets passed to the `std::complex<T>(T)` constructor, where `T` is `double`. Result: complex number with undefined real part and `0.0` imaginary part.

Comment: @Mike great clarification, wouldn't know how to say it better. just hit me how much I mentally skip steps once I know the answer.

Comment: C++14 adds the numeric literal syntax `1.i`, `3.5if`, `4.0000001il`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `math.h` header in C++ provides the following overloads of `sqrt`:

```
auto sqrt( float arg ) -> float;
auto sqrt( double arg ) -> double;
auto sqrt( long double arg ) -> long double;
auto sqrt( Integral arg ) -> double;    // C++11 and later
```

where `Integral` denotes any integral type (this is a set of overloads or a function template).

The `<complex>` header additionally defines this overload:

```
template< class T >
auto sqrt( complex<T> const& x ) -> complex<T>;
```

There's also an overload for `valarray`, but it's not relevant here.

When you use `-1` as actual argument, like

```
sqrt( -1 )
```

the direct match of the argument type, the overload with `Integral` argument, is best fit, and that overload returns a `double`.

There is no way to represent the mathematical *i* as a `double` value. So the value that you get is an implementation-defined value (if your C++ implementation's `double` type supports NaN, *Not a Number*, it can be a NaN); “whether the integer
expression `errno` acquires the value `EDOM` is implementation-defined” according to C99 §7.12.1/2. To avoid that you can make sure that the `-1` is converted to an argument of type `complex<double>`, say:

```
sqrt( complex<double>( -1 ) )
```

With the compilers I tried this yields the same result as writing

```
complex<double>( 0, 1 )
```

which represents the mathematical *i*, the square root of minus 1.

Comment: [The C++ reference for sqrt I found](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/) makes no mention of the return value when the input is negative, so I'm figuring it's undefined behavior. You might or might not get a NaN.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com is generally a better reference, but in [this case](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) it contained pure disinformation: "If a domain error occurs, an implementation-defined value is returned (NaN where supported)". The C99 standard instead says that "A domain error occurs if
the argument is less than zero.", and C++11 says "If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function
or a pointer invalid for its intended use), the behavior is undefined". Thanks!, corrected.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I disagree: [res.on.arguments]/1, which you quote, says "unless explicitly stated otherwise", and it is in fact explicitly stated otherwise for the cmath functions.

Comment: @Cubbi: Yes, the C99 standard, which is incorporated into C++11, does state otherwise. Almost but not quite the same as cppreference.com: C++99 §7.12.1/2 "On a
domain error, the function returns an implementation-defined value; whether the integer
expression `errno` acquires the value `EDOM` is implementation-defined". The difference is the cppreference.com makes a requirement of returning NaN where that is support, without that being actually required by the standard, AFAICS. So my original wording before Mike's comment was more correct. Fixing. Thanks!

Comment: C99 makes it a requirement to return NaN where Ieee math is supported (granted the general-purpose "if supported" was taken from posix). I guess I could be even more pedantic and say something like "typically" in the non-ieee part

Comment: @Cubbi: do you have a quote for the C99 NaN requirement? I didn't find it. Now on machine sans docs.

Comment: Appendix F, although for sqrt alone of all math functions it defers to the floating point math iso document. (now in a car sans doc)